# How to parse a JSON string using PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing

I have a JSON string that has 1-n numbers of lat/lng records. It looks something like this:

```
{\"lat\":37.790388261934424,\"lng\":-122.46047996826172},{\"lat\":37.789608231530124,\"lng\":-122.46344112701416}
```

What is a good way to parse this to get lat/lng values loop?  And do the escaped double quotes impact the parsing?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: try [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Why does it have those slashes in it??

Comment: Because it is wrapped in double quotes.

Comment: @lucifurious: probably because magic_quotes_gpc is turned on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ll = '[{"lat":37.790388261934424,"lng":-122.46047996826172},{"lat":37.789608231530124,"lng":-122.46344112701416}]';
$ll = json_decode($ll);
print_r($ll);
```

Prints...

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [lat] => 37.7903882619
            [lng] => -122.460479968
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [lat] => 37.7896082315
            [lng] => -122.463441127
        )

)
```

Comment: This answer is missing its education explanation.

Answer (score 5):

Use [json_decode.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

You will need to unescape quotes first; just use

```
$unescaped_data = str_replace('\"','"',$data)
```

Comment: This is not enough.  The input string would still not be valid json after calling `str_replace()`.

Answer (score 3):

In your case it's probably best to use:

```
$array = json_decode(stripslashes("[$input_string]"), 1);
```

Note that you will lose some precision on your float values in PHP.

Comment: Is there a way to preserve the precision of the float values in PHP with this operation? They float values are pretty important.

Comment: If he wrapped it in double quotes, he doesn't need to escape string. His JSON is missing `[]` around `{},{}` like you have shown. @Genadinik, 9 decimals is not enough for Lat and Lon?

Comment: @Genadinik: Not with json_decode. And you cannot handle more precise numbers in PHP, it only knows `float`. The lost precision is minimal, and I actually suspect the Javascript representation is not overly exact either. (A workaround would involve parsing by hand, and using the gmp functions for all coordinates: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php - in your whole application.)

Comment: It works form me, even though the data are inserted into array, so I have to retrieve it using array[0]['data']

Answer (score 1):

[JSON_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and remove escape quotes