# parse json in php, json objects and json arrays

Tags: php, json, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse a JSON string using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527065/how-to-parse-a-json-string-using-php)

this is my data object

```
{
  "data": {
    "translations": [
      {
        "translatedText": "Hallo Welt"
      },
      {
        "translatedText": "Hallo Berlin"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

how do I parse this using PHP?

this is a jsonObject that contains jsonObject("data") that contains jsonArray that contains jsonObjects at each index that contains key/value "translatedText"

this is what I have and my assumption

```
$jsonResult = json_decode($data);
$translated_text = $jsonResult->data->translations[0]->translatedText;`
```

Comment: Have you tried: `json_decode()`?

Comment: Have you tried: `var_dump($jsonResult);`?

Comment: Actually, this is a fair question. If you come to PHP from other languages PHP handles JSON differently. There are no jsonArray or jsonObject types in PHP (like in Java or C#).

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = json_decode($json_element, true);
```

to make associative array.

Answer (score 1):

I'm think this is what it would be. json_decode does not parse to a PHP object, but to just an array.

```
$jsonResult = json_decode($data);
$translated_text = $jsonResult['data']['translations'][0]['translatedText'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = json_decode($json_element);
```