# Create php script to parse this json

Tags: php, json, parsing

I wanna to parse this json data in php, could any one help me in the script.

Code below

> { members": [
>           {
>               "member": {
>                   "id": 464258,
>                   "display_name": "test1",
>                   "mitch_rank_index": 6.64,
>                   "distance": 0.56009166639932,
>                   "unread_messages_from": 0,
>                   "explorer": false,
>                   "online": true,
>                   "favourite": false,
>                   "fan": false,
>                   "thumbnail_url": "link",
>                   "profile_photo_url": "link"
>               }
>           },
>           {
>               "member": {
>                   "id": 1009345,
>                   "display_name": "Test2",
>                   "mitch_rank_index": 6.32,
>                   "distance": 0.583112841628013,
>                   "unread_messages_from": 0,
>                   "explorer": false,
>                   "online": false,
>                   "favourite": false,
>                   "fan": false,
>                   "thumbnail_url": "link",
>                   "profile_photo_url": "Link"
>               }
>           },
>           {
>               "member": {
>                   "id": 1052568,
>                   "display_name": null,
>                   "mitch_rank_index": 5.699999999999999,
>                   "distance": 0.597684462292014,
>                   "unread_messages_from": 0,
>                   "explorer": false,
>                   "online": true,
>                   "favourite": false,
>                   "fan": false,
>                   "thumbnail_url": "link",
>                   "profile_photo_url": "link"
>               }
>           }
>       ]

}

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [about StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: Look at [`json_decode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse a JSON string using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527065/how-to-parse-a-json-string-using-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a valid json and array generated from it. Treat it as you would treat a PHP array.

```
<?php

$json = <<<JSON
{
    "members": [
        {
            "member": {
                "id": 464258,
                "display_name": "test1",
                "mitch_rank_index": 6.64,
                "distance": 0.56009166639932,
                "unread_messages_from": 0,
                "explorer": false,
                "online": true,
                "favourite": false,
                "fan": false,
                "thumbnail_url": "link",
                "profile_photo_url": "link"
            }
        },
        {
            "member": {
                "id": 1009345,
                "display_name": "Test2",
                "mitch_rank_index": 6.32,
                "distance": 0.583112841628013,
                "unread_messages_from": 0,
                "explorer": false,
                "online": false,
                "favourite": false,
                "fan": false,
                "thumbnail_url": "link",
                "profile_photo_url": "Link"
            }
        },
        {
            "member": {
                "id": 1052568,
                "display_name": null,
                "mitch_rank_index": 5.699999999999999,
                "distance": 0.597684462292014,
                "unread_messages_from": 0,
                "explorer": false,
                "online": true,
                "favourite": false,
                "fan": false,
                "thumbnail_url": "link",
                "profile_photo_url": "link"
            }
        }
    ]
}
JSON;

$json = json_decode($json,true);

print("<pre>");
print_r($json);
print("</pre>");

?>
```

**UPDATE**

To show all IDs from your JSON you can take an example from the following code

```
// $ids will contain array of all ID that ara available in JSON
foreach ($json['members'] as $members) $ids[] = $members['member']['id'];

// you can use $ids array from now
// following code just shows how array can look like in php
print("<pre>");
print_r($ids);
print("</pre>");

// use foreach to go through all IDs and do something for each of them
// this code simply goes through all IDs and prints each of them on screen
// again, this is a way to manipulate through all IDS from your JSON
foreach ($ids as $id)
{
    // you can use $id here in this loop
    print("id: ".$id."<br />");
}
```

Comment: Thanks what should i do to display only the the IDs from this json.

Comment: To display only the IDs from this JSON take a look at the **updated answer**

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
json_decode()
```

You can read more about this function here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php